# Reverse engineering form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using a hosted cart system to manage a ecommerce platform. The system uses form submission to add items to the user's cart. I want to write a javascript library to allow me to add things to the cart with JS, but I will need to see what the platform is submitting so I can copy it appropriately.

Any advice how to best sniff out what the default form info is getting submitted to the form so I can copy it via jquery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your browser's console; Chrome has it built-in, Firefox has Firebug.

The entire request will be viewable in the network tab.

Another, more-complicated option is to set up a trivial local proxy and dump the request.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was possible but couldn't find the request in the network tab. Got it now. //hat tip

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/). It's a nice addon for Firefox that let's you view and edit this data.

Firebug and it's derivatives also has the functionality if you have that.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug on firefox using the console and turn on 'persist' it will tell you whats going on after the page posts and stuff.  :)